# Backbone/Vimeo API - View logging but not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am currently learning Backbone and trying to build my first app. As a learning tool, I'm attempting to render a Vimeo gallery by user id.

I have everything put together, and my view is logging correctly, but it will not render to the page. I've been trying to solve this for hours, but I am not sure where I've gone wrong. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Is my approach correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Backbone App</title>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="video-container">
  <script type="text/template" id="video_template">
    <h1><%= video_title %></h1>
  </script>
</div>

<script>

(function($){

  var vimeoUser = 9836759;

  var Video = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  var VideoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Video
  });

  var VideoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
      var variables = {video_title: this.model.attributes.title};
      var template = _.template($('#video_template').html(), variables);
      // Logging element works
      console.log(template);
      // Rendering does not work
      this.$el.html( template );
    }
  });

  var GalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize: function(){
      this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
      this.collection.each(function(video){
        var videoView = new VideoView({ model: video});
      }, this);
    }
  });

  // Create instance of VideoCollection
  var VideoGallery = new VideoCollection;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/' + vimeoUser + '/videos.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
      // map api results to our collection
      var videos = _.map(response, function(video) {
        return {
          title: video.title,
          details: video.description,
          thumbnail_large: video.thumbnail_large,
          video: 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + video.id + '?api=1&player_id=vimeo-player&autoplay=1'
        }
      });

      // add vimeo videos to collection
      VideoGallery.add(videos);
      var galleryView = new GalleryView({ el: $('#video-container'), collection: VideoGallery });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an element on the `VideoView`, so it's just rendering to `li` that isn't attached to the DOM.  I would suggest something like this:

```
 var self = this;
 this.collection.each(function(video){
     var container = $("<li>");
     self.$el.append(container);
     var videoView = new VideoView({ el: container, model: video});
 }, this);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhLdf/6/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great and makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, `render` simply fills in the view's `el` but doesn't touch the DOM. The usual pattern goes like this:

```
var v = new View(...)
v.render();
$(container).append(v.el);
```

Usually `render` returns `this` so you'll often see:

```
$(container).append(v.render().el);
```

First adjust all your `render` methods to end with `return this;`. Then adjust things to update the DOM:

```
var VideoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  //...
  render: function() {
    //...
    return this; // <---------- Add this
  }
});

var GalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  //...
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(video){
      var videoView = new VideoView({ model: video });
      this.$el.append(videoView.el); // <---------- Add this
    });
    return this; // <---------- Add this
  }
});
```

Your `GalleryView` is set up to create a `<ul>` as its `el` so 
you'll want to say:

```
var galleryView = new GalleryView({ collection: VideoGallery });
$('#video-container').append(galleryView.el);
```

to crank everything up.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is also correct, but I could only accept one. Thank you for the detailed explanation, I understand the pattern much better now. Unfortunately I cannot up vote as I'm new to Stack Overflow.